# Point cloudflare to s3 bucket (not website endpoint)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

Traditionally, I used s3 website endpoints, but is there a way to point cloudflare to an s3 bucket (`s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/index.html`) instead? One of the requirements I have is to use SSL on the origin, and this seems to be the only way.

I have no problem doing this with cloudfront by configuring the root object. However, I'm not sure if that's an aws-specific feature. It would be great to accomplish this by using cloudflare as well.

Comment: The ability to set a default root object (not to be confused with the ability to specify an index document -- it's not the same but it is similar in behavior at the root of the entire bucket) is indeed a CloudFront feature, not an S3 feature... and it sounds like what you're asking is how to configure a default root object -- or similar behavior -- with Cloudflare, while using the REST endpoint of the bucket as the origin.  Is that right?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yep. Well, if it's specific to cloudfront, I may need to look elsewhere then. Bummer. I'd use cloudfront, but the high traffic costs are what made me look into cloudflare.

Comment: It may sound strange, but you could do Cloudflare → CloudFront → S3.  That should cost essentially the same as Cloudflare → S3, possibly cheaper depending on the region of the bucket and configuration of CloudFront (using S3 with CloudFront can actually cost less than S3 alone).  Any performance difference should be difficult to measure.

Comment: Doesn't sound strange at all. The cost is amortized either way, like you said. I'm heavily biased toward aws and its long-term services so I'll definitely try this out!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it, assuming hte objects are publicly readable.  From some cursory tests, I have concluded that the public S3 https endpoint works independently from the hosted website thing ( which , I suppose, is really more of a virtual host mapping to the bucket than anything else)

The URL is indeed of the form https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object-key and the objects have to be public.